# awk print several substring

Tags: awk, substring

I would like to be able to print several substrings via awk. 
Here an example of what I usually do;

```
awk' {print substr($0,index($0,string),10)} ' test.txt > result.txt
```

This allow me to print 10 letters after the discovery of my string.
But the result is the first one substring, instead of several as I expected.

Here an example if I use the string "ATGC" :

test.txt

```
ATGCATATAAATGCTTTTTTTTT
```

result.txt

```
ATGCATATAA
```

instead of

```
ATGCATATAA
ATGCTTTTTT
```

What I have to add ?

I'm sure the answer is easy for you guys !
Thank you for your help.

Comment: What should the output be given input like `ATGCTTTATGCTTTTTT` where `ATGC` occurs within the 10 chars after the preceding `ATGC`?

Comment: If another ATGC appears in the 10 chars after the first ATGC, I want to be able to have these 10 chars too. With your example, I would like to be able to recover    ATGCTTTATG and     ATGCTTTTTT.

Comment: That's an enormously important use case that you should have included in your sample input/output. Please add it now. Also - what if there aren't 10 chars after ATGC, should anything be output or not? Include that case too and any other non-sunny-day cases you can think of. Once you've done that then we can start to help you.

Comment: I just wanted to start to understand how basic awk language works, to have something more fast than what I code in R to do this exact analysis, which encounter all these kind of possibilities of course that you talk about (overlap, size, even strand).
I didn't want you do all the job, that is why I haven't precise all these parameters ; I just wanted a start solution to be able to learn a little, and then try to build the rest.

Comment: You didn't get a start solution though, you got a solution to the problem you asked about and so it is completely different from and not in any way applicable to the problem you actually have. if you [edit] your question to describe your real requirements with more truly representative sample input/output THEN you'll probably get an answer which may be a start or may solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gawk (gnu awk), you can make use of `FPAT`:

```
awk -v FPAT='ATGC.{6}' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' file
```

With your example:

```
$ awk -v FPAT='ATGC.{6}' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' <<<"ATGCATATAAATGCTTTTTTTTT"                                                                                  
ATGCATATAA                                                                                                                                                                 
ATGCTTTTTT
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I knew there was something to do with this NF, but didn't know how to apply it. I'm going to try your answer right now, and tell you if it's work. Thank you again.

Comment: So it's working with no problem.
But, as @Ed_Morton ask me previously, is it possible to add a last modification to be able to recover two seauences, instead of just one, in case of a second ATGC appears before 10 chars ?
Like :
 `$ awk -v FPAT='ATGC.{6}' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}' <<<"ATGCATGCAATTCC"

ATGCATGCAA`
but also ATGCAATTCC ?

Comment: That's not a `last modification` it's a complete rewrite.

Comment: Oh ok ! Then I will keep this for the moment, and see how I can fix the rest later.

Comment: To be clear, there is no fixing it later. This approach is perfect for the problem you asked about but it **cannot** be adapted to work for your real problem. You'd need to start over with a whole new approach to the problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,10),RS substr($0,length -12,10)}' file

ATGCATATAA 
ATGCTTTTTT
```

Comment: Hi, 
With some of my previous codes in awk, and some sed, I have finally managed to do what I wanted exactly. 

Thank you for your help.